# I had trouble with Android Studio Project

Tags: android, eclipse

When I import a Eclipse project to Android Studio,I met this issue  as this image

[image]

Please give me a help,thanks!

Comment: I recommend fixing your question. As it stands now your destined for down votes and a potential closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the original project made a mistake with the way they added files to the project. For example they may have created a project with the path /home/them/Projects/MYPROJECT. Then they added a file that was in /home/them/Documents/Document. (You can add files by pressing file->add)

Then when you imported it copied all the files when importing it created a copy of the project under /home/you/Wherever/you/put/the/project. However it doesn't copy files in /home/them/Documents/ but the project is still referencing ../../File.

The solution. You need to get that file and import it into your project. I recommend also importing it into the project directory and not just creating a reference like the previous developer did.